# Link to another page with bookmarks via javascript, it's possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bookmarks

In practice, I would like by clicking on one of the items A, B, C, etc. in the page 1, from the same menu in the page 2 that opens, it opened the above page (page 2) and have displayed the  corresponding to the clicked in the page 1 hiding the others.

in the page 1 will be:

```
<div id="Menu" class="pointer_p">
    <a onclick="return Menu('1',this)" class="hover_red_white_p"><p>A</p></a>
    <a onclick="return Menu('2',this)" class="hover_red_white_p"><p>B</p></a>
    <a onclick="return Menu('3',this)" class="hover_red_white_p"><p>C</p></a>
    <a onclick="return Menu('4',this)" class="hover_red_white_p"><p>D</p></a>
    <a onclick="return Menu('5',this)" class="hover_red_white_p"><p>E</p></a>
    <a onclick="return Menu('6',this)" class="hover_red_white_p"><p>F</p></a>
    <a onclick="return Menu('7',this)" class="hover_red_white_p"><p>G</p></a>
    <a onclick="return Menu('8',this)"></a>
    <a onclick="return Menu('9',this)"></a>
    <a onclick="return Menu('10',this)"></a>
</div>
```

This is the page that will open in the page 2:

http://jsfiddle.net/5faG7/2/

So, to be clear, if I click on the item A will open a page where you will see the  containing "1" and the others will remain hidden, if the B  containing "2" and the other hidden and so on for C, D, E, etc..

Thanks in advance for the help... :)

Answer (score 0):

It'll be easier if you use jQuery.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="" data-page="1">A</a>
    <a href="" data-page="2">B</a>
    <a href="" data-page="3">C</a>
    <a href="" data-page="4">D</a>
    ...
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div data-page="1" style="display:none;">Text for page 1</div>
    <div data-page="2" style="display:none;">Text for page 2</div>
    <div data-page="3" style="display:none;">Text for page 3</div>
    <div data-page="4" style="display:none;">Text for page 4</div>
    ...
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu a").click(function(){
                    // Hide all the other menu items
                    $("#menu a[data-page!='" + page_name + "']").hide();
                    // Show the current menu item
                    $("#menu a[data-page='" + page_name + "']").show();
                    // Get the page name
        var page_name = $(this).data("page");
        // Hide all the pages
        $("#content div").hide();
        // Show the selected page
        $("#content div[data-page='" + page_name + "']").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand how it should work, because the page 2 that you find working in the link must always be able to show and hide the <div> inside the page. I want to add a function in page 1. Clicking on an item identified by its ID must open the page 2 which directly displays the <div> corresponding the element you clicked in page 1 hiding the other as already happens in page 2, the difference is that the request to display the <div> is made from page 1

Comment: I updated the code.
I didn't understand whether you want to display "one menu item at a time" or not.

Comment: Yes, one item at a time, as well as works on page 2 http://jsfiddle.net/5faG7/2/ ... What I didn't understand from your code is what goes in page 1 and what in page 2...!!!

Comment: I don't understand your request.

If you have a menu and you want to open ONE page at a time, then the following code does this: `var page_name = $(this).data("page");
        // Hide all the pages
        $("#content div").hide();
        // Show the selected page
        $("#content div[data-page='" + page_name + "']").show();`

Comment: If you're looking to hide PART of the menu each time you click on a menu item, then this code does this: `// Hide all the other menu items
                    $("#menu a[data-page!='" + page_name + "']").hide();
                    // Show the current menu item
                    $("#menu a[data-page='" + page_name + "']").show();`